# Can't 'store' itertools grouper object for later use?

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

My python mission for the day is to learn the `itertools` module, but unfortunately I am stuck on the `groupby` class. I know how it works but I can't seem to figure out why I can't `store` an iterator for later use.

```
from random import randint, choice
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from itertools import *

alist = []
while len(alist) != 50:
    alist.append((choice(letters),randint(1,10)))    #tuples of random numbers and letters

alist.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

unique = []

for key , group in groupby(alist, lambda x: x[1]):
    unique.append((key,group))
    for g in group:      #here I can iterate over the grouper object
        print g      

for x in unique:
    print "Special key is %d" % x[0]
    for i in x[1]:     #here i can't loop through iterator
        print i
```

Why can't I go through the grouper object in the second loop where i run through `unique`?  I only get the `print "Special key is %d"` statement 10 times.

Comment: The groups are not independent; being tied to the underlying iterator, when you advance to the next group the preceding groups can no longer be accessed. This is clearly documented.

Comment: So I can only access the groups in the `groupby` loop?

Comment: You can copy each group to a list as you iterate.